# Why FASM.dll not merging with program?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I would like to merge my program, yet the same error pops up every time:

```
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\blazingsh.it\blazingsh.it\bin\Release\FASM.dll'. Skipping and processing rest of arguments.
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args
```

At first I thought the FASM.dll file was unnecessary and threw it away, but after running the combined files the program kept crashing. This FASM.dll file is responsible for injecting dll files from computer into processes, I used it from github "https://github.com/Reloaded-Project/Reloaded.Injector". I wrote an e-mail to the owner of this assembly but he still does not write me back. That is why I am asking for help here. Many times this site helps when there is an error but this one is really special. Greetings.

Comment: I don't see FASM in the Reloaded.Injector project.

Comment: Is FASM definitely an assembly and not a normal binary DLL?

Comment: Somewhere in your project you should have a reference to FAMS.dll. It could be direct or via NuGet package. If this is the case the assembly is automatically copied to the output directory

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at [single file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview). This is much newer, and I would expect it to be more reliable.